# Lambda capture of variadic arguments in constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming

I'm trying capture variadic arguments in a lambda within a constructor initialization list. Here is a simple example that illustrates the issue.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void foo(int a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

template<typename ...Args>
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget(std::function<void(Args...)> f, Args... args)
        : _f([=]() { f(args...); })  // compiler error here
    {
    }

    void print() const { _f(); }

private:
    std::function<void()> _f;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Widget<int> w(foo, 7);
    w.print();    
    return 0;
}
```

In VS2013 I'm getting the following compile errors:

```
error C3546: '...' : there are no parameter packs available to expand
error C2065: 'args' : undeclared identifier
```

The following versions of the `Widget` constructor compile and work.

```
Widget(std::function<void(Args...)> f, Args... args)
{
    _f = [=]() { f(args...); };
}

Widget(std::function<void(Args...)> f, Args... args)
    : _f(std::bind(f, args...))
{
}
```

**Update:** The MS Visual C++ Compiler Team have fixed this issue and will include it in the upcoming release of Visual C++ ([see](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1230353/lambda-capture-of-variadic-arguments-in-constructor-initialization-list)).

Comment: Looks like another bug.

Comment: Yes, it does look like a bug. I've filed a report with MS Connect.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda captures are probably the last part of C++11 that a compiler ends up implementing, and it wouldn't be surprising if a particular compiler hasn't yet implemented it, or if its implementation is buggy. gcc, supposedly, didn't get this right until recently.

The typical approach is to work around this using tuples. Use `std::make_tuple` to put all your variadic parameters into a tuple, and then capture the tuple.

Then, convert the tuple back to the parameter pack. Search stackoverflow, there are several examples of how to do that.

That's going to generate a whole bunch of baggage code. But it is, what it is, and when the compiler finally gets it right, this workaround can be dropped, and in the meantime you'll have something that works. More or less.

Comment: Thanks. tuples will work. `std::bind` works correctly and assigning the function to a lambda within the constructor body also works, so these are good work-arounds.